# How can I use ubuntu bionic sources to download specific python packages on ubuntu trusty

Tags: ubuntu, python, ubuntu-16.04, ubuntu-18.04

Can I install python3.7 on ubuntu 16.04 using official ubuntu sources from ubuntu18.04.I just want to install python3.7 and it's dev and nothing else using that source

I am aware of ppa/deadsnakes and building from source but want to explore this option

Comment: Try this site to accomplish what you want:

https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-python-3-7-on-ubuntu-18-04/

Comment: @John I mentioned that this is something I don't want to use unless there isn't another way